# Unable to run Sakis3g after downgrading to gnome 2?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, downgrade

After downgrading to Gnome 2 from Gnome 3 in Ubuntu 11.04 I was unable to run sakis3g.
Whenever I run it nothing open up. Yes I have checked to execute the script in permissions.
I was able to open it before upgrading to Gnome 3.

error message

```
** (zenity:3386): WARNING **: Could not load ui file /usr/share/zenity/zenity.ui: Failed to open file '/usr/share/zenity/zenity.ui': No such file or directory

** (zenity:3471): WARNING **: Could not load ui file /usr/share/zenity/zenity.ui: Failed to open file '/usr/share/zenity/zenity.ui': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try running sakis3g from a terminal.  Any errors displayed?  Copy and paste the errors into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message, I would suggestion you either need to install zenity or force a reinstall.

Try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zenity
```